# Django user groups only for permissions?

Tags: django, database-design

I'm a bit unsure what to use Django user groups for.

I have an application where every user belongs to a different organisation. The organisations don't have anything to do with read/write permissions. It's just a way to separate groups of users. Every organisation needs some additional fields, like a name, URL, and email address. New organisations will be added to the system over time.
Within every organisation, users can have different permissions for moderation and administration, for which I (also) want to use user groups.

My question: Should I use Django's user groups to define the organisations, or should I just make an 'Organisation' model with a relation to the user?

Comment: Be aware that permissions in django apply to entire models, not instances within those models. For example, your "OrgA" group can have access to modify ALL organisations, or NO organisations. You might want to look into django-guardian or something similar for object-level-permissions.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Are you sure about this? Maybe it changed because in Django 1.8 official doc I can read this: **Permissions can be set not only per type of object, but also per specific object instance**

Comment: @DavidD. the API exists for instance level permissions, but the built in django permissions do not use them (from memory). That's why I suggested other django packages that actually use the instance level permission APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. User groups are made for different reasons. You CAN use them to define organisations but  I think you should think bit further ahead:

- will the organisation require more fields than just name?
- perhaps you will need permissions in the future to define users roles within organisations?

I'm sure you can come up with more things to think of. But if you answered yes to one of those questions then just create your Organisation model.

Comment: The answer to your question is definitely yes, so I guess I go with your advice and make my own Organisation model. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

1) You need to add `group` from `django admin` side under `group` table.

2) And while creating new user, assign specific `group` to `user` using `user_obj.groups.add(group_id)`. Or Let user select `group` at frontend.

and then `user_obj.save()`

in `Group` table, you can create `organization`

**OR**

You can create individual `organization` table and assign assign user to specific organization.

Comment: So I am suggesting  that use group table as an organization. instead of creating new one. because there is already a relationship between user and group table.

Comment: Then that's probably the wrong decision. OP doesn't need a single organisation group. They need many different groups, each with extra fields on it.

Comment: He can override group table at his django project and add new fields in that.

Comment: That's not a good option either. Things like that should not require overwriting existing functionality - they should be rather extending that functionality. But extending Group object will create new table anyway. So why not just create new table for Organisation.

Comment: By hacking the source? Or.. they could just define a new model. There's nothing inherently special about the group model, except that it allows the admin to specify and use permissions on a group of users rather than a single user. The type of permissions OP wants will not work with Groups anyway.

Comment: Same I am saying, instead of group table just rename it to Organization and link with user table by passing foreign key organization to user.